# json content acces with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I needed to load and read JSON file with pure JS. It looks like that:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "data.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        data= JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
console.log(data);
```

I am getting an error saying that data data is not defined. Why?

Comment: that's bcoz you're trying to eat the pizza before baking it :), remember ajax is asynchronous

Comment: move the `console.log` under `data= JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)`

Comment: Works. It was becouse of asynchronous call. Post was a duplicate. Sorry, my bad.